# Cannot clone repo from git daemon

Tags: git, git-daemon

Noob question.

I can't really clone a very basic repo which I am serving through a daemon.

**On one terminal**

```
cd /repos

$ git daemon --export-all --reuseaddr --informative-errors --verbose
[12680] Ready to rumble
[16420] Connection from [::1]:51277
[16420] unable to set SO_KEEPALIVE on socket: Input/output error
[16420] Extended attribute "host": localhost
[16420] Request upload-pack for '/helloWorld'
[16420] '/helloWorld' does not appear to be a git repository
```

**On another terminal**

```
$ git clone git://localhost/helloWorld network_helloWorld
Cloning into 'network_helloWorld'...
fatal: remote error: no such repository: /helloWorld
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution?